# How to install oald8 in linuxmint 16?

Tags: package-management

Hello I tried to install oald8 in linux mint 16 petra 64 bits using the following command 
 ~/Desktop/Oxford/linux $ linux32 sh ./setup.sh.

during the installation I got these error massages at the last:

"Install fonts
cp: cannot stat ‘setup.data/AWLPhonetics3U.TTF’: No such file or directory
./fonts.scale: fopen(w): Permission denied
./fonts.dir: fopen(w): Permission denied
 Install desktop shortcut
Installation complete."

Now I can open oald8 but with no sound and a pop of massage "This page contains information of a type (application/x-shockwave-flash) that can only be viewed with the appropirate plug-in "

Answer (score 0):

"AWLPhonetics3U.TTF: No such file or directory" sounds as if you're being bitten by a case-sensitive file system of UNIX - on Windows it doesn't matter whether a file ends in .TTF or .ttf, but on Linux it does.

Permission errors can be because you are not the super user, or because the installation routine tries to execute some script that doesn't have the explicit "is executable" bit set. That is also something that matters on Unix only.

What is OALD? It looks as if it's a windows program that someone has ported to UNIX with a certain lack of attention to detail.

Comment: OALD is the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.